# what is the meaning of Disallow: /search in robot.txt?

Tags: seo, blogger

I found this in my root.txt file

Disallow: /search

what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a robots.txt file, then it indicates to web crawlers that they are to avoid going into URLs beginning with /search on that host. Your robots.txt file is related to the [Robots Exclusion Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

You mention "robot.txt" in the question title and "root.txt" in the body. If this is indeed a robots.txt file, it needs to be named "robots.txt", otherwise it has no effect at all.

Comment: Also, if `Disallow: /search` would be the *only* content of the file, it wouldn't work, as the `User-agent:` line is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It instructions robots/crawlers/spiders that they shouldn't access anything within that folder, or variants of that URL, such as the following examples:

```
/search
/search?term=x
/search/page/
/search/category=y&term=x
/search/category-name/term/
```

With regards to the comments above on how this affects *indexation* (whether or not a search engine or other entity will catalogue the URL), none of them are quite correct.

It should be noted that instructions in a robots.txt file are *crawl* directives, not *indexation* directives. Whilst compliant bots will read the robots.txt file prior to requesting a URL and determine whether or not they're allowed to crawl it, disallow rules do not prevent indexation (nor even, in the case of non-compliant bots, prevent access/crawling/scraping).

You'll see instances periodically of search results in Google with a meta description alluding to the page having been included though inaccessible; something along the lines of "we weren't able to show a description because we're not allowed to crawl this page". This typically happens when Google (or w/e) encounters a disallowed URL, but believes that the URL should still be catalogued - in Google's case, this typically occurs when a highly linked and/or authoritative URL is disallowed.

To prevent indexation, you're much better off using an on-page meta tag, or even an x-robots http header (particularly useful for non-page resources, such as PDFs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

**"Disallow: /search"** tells search engine robots not to index and crawl those links which contains "**/search**" For example if the link is http://yourblog.blogspot.com/search.html/bla-bla-bla then robots won't crawl and index this link.